# Ndef message. How read it from sector 4

Tags: ndef

I've read several pdfs about decoding NDEF messages in NTag215 type 2. I figured out this:

- the first sector 4 bytes, 0,1,2 for ID 3 for BCC0 (what does it mean?);
- second sector 4 bytes for ID;
- third sector BCC1 lock bytes and a byte that I don't remember, but they are not rewritable anyway;
- fourth sector CC;
- from the fifth sector, address 0x04, the NDEF message begins.
  I can't understand these 8 bytes
  04] .  03 1B 91 01
  05] .  06 54 02 65
  Or rather, I don't understand the first 6 bytes, the seventh is the UTF8 encoding 02 (seventh bit is 0 else UTF16 with 2 bytes for lenght of language type), and the eighth is the e of "en" which ends in the first byte of sector 0x06.  54 should be the T of Text.
  06] .  6E 70 6C 61
  the sector 0x06 then starts with the n of "en" and then with the first 3 bytes of the payload.
  07] .  51 01 0D 54
  here 51 is payload closing byte?
  In summary, I don't quite understand the first seven bytes of the NDEF Message and how the record is constructed, i.e. where the record header begins and how the payload ends.  Can you help me understand?